# Como hago para modificar un módulo ya creado (Quitando y agregando campos)?? En Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, openerp

Quisiera saber como hago para modificar un moduló ya creado en Odoo. Por ejemplo el modulo de empleados. Modificarlo agregando mis campos y mis parámetros respectivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar debes crear un módulo, y dentro de este módulo una modelo con

```js
class Employee(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.employee"

    place_of_birth = fields.Char('Place of Birth')
```

De esta forma le estamos adicionando el campo place_of_birth al modelo hr.employee

Para mostrar este campo en la vista se debe heredar la vista de la siguiente forma:

```html
<record id="hr_view_employee_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
 <field name="name">hr_view_employee_form_inherit</field>
 <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
 <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
 <field name="arch" type="xml">
  <data>
   <field name="user_id" position="after">
     <field name="place_of_birth"/>
   </field>                    
  </data>
 </field>
</record>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda esta explicación.
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me fue de mucha utilidad.

Comment: Y para quitar campos que no necesito como podria hacer?

Comment: Puedes ponerlos en invisible o sobre escribirlos position="replace" pero de esta forma se eliminan de la vista y si son utilizados en otro lugar van a dar errores. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la herencia de Odoo como te explicaron anteriormente, poner campos, antes o despues de un campo o desaparecerlos, para todo esto usas XPATH https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/xml/xpath.html aqui tienes documentacion de ello. Pero si es importante que sepas, que cuando ocultas campos o renombras del padre, si hay  otro modulo conviviendo con el tuyo puede ser que le de problema si esta utilizando este mismo modulo, por ejemplo es comun heredar el partner si cambias algo , cambiara para todos los que de el hereden incluso de otro modulo